# SFDC's out-of-the-box email to case security standards

Tags: apex, email, security

We are in the midst of HITRUST certification info-gathering and remediation steps, and because we have SFDC's out-of-the-box email to case as a communication tool, we are looking to understand its security standards.
I've searched the Salesforce Help page, but have not found documentation on the encryption standards of this tool.

1. Where can I find an appropriate description and proof that our SFDC instance is using encryption on this email tool?
2. What is the email encryption standard for Emails going out of salesforce?
3. How do people handle encrypting emails with Salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find an appropriate description and proof that our SFDC instance is using encryption on this email tool?

[TLS and security for emails and 'Email-to-Case'](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000322936&type=1) covers the general description of inbound and outbound emails. [Set Up Transaction Layer Security (TLS)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_set_up_tls.htm&type=5) covers the actual settings for outbound emails.

For inbound emails, such as support@mycompany.com that are then forwarded to Email-to-Case, that's your server, you control the rules. Salesforce will accept incoming emails encrypted or not, and there's no way to stop Salesforce from accepting unencrypted email connections that I know of.

> What is the email encryption standard for Emails going out of salesforce?

For outgoing emails, you can choose from four different options. The default is to try and negotiate TLS and use it if available ("preferred"). You can choose to add a "verify" option to verify certificates, and you can choose between "preferred" and "required." If required, the email will not be sent if TLS cannot be enabled (or verified, if selected). The choice is yours, you can make it as secure as you desire.

> How do people handle encrypting emails with Salesforce?

They can set the Email Deliverability settings to meet any outbound requirements. Incoming emails are set by the organization's email servers.